# Visual Studio: inability to overwrite current file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dialog, ide, save

Lately I've been struggling with quite weird and frustrating problem. There doesn't seem to be any information about it anywhere.

While working on any project for a while Visual Studio randomly asks me to "Save File As" when I want to compile my app. That itself is behavior I didn't use to see. When I try to overwrite the file however, I can't do that because it's being used by another process (IDE that I'm working in obviously). So unless I create new file (and therefore create mess in app's directory) or save it somewhere else I'm unable to run my app.

Reinstalling and searching trough VS' setting didn't help.

[Random dialog that pops up when I try to run my app. (OS is in Polish)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adkK8.png)

Comment: Are you sure your anti-virus isn't locking the file? Usually the IDE doesn't open the file and hold it open, it just opens it, reads it, and then you work in a buffer, it shouldn't be holding the file open. Try using Process Explorer to find out what is really attached to that file.

Comment: Is it the executable itself that's locked? Are you doing work in other threads that aren't ending?

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't think so. Everything was fine for months and it started occurring recently. I excluded my projects' directory from Avast's scanning however.

Comment: @john No, just source code file seems to be locked by IDE or some other process.